# Is it possible to write dynamic templated UDF for GCP Dataflow in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a scenario where I need to read some files in DataFlow, transform the data, then write the result to a BigQuery table. I need to support a few different formats for the files however. So I want to create a generic solution to enable flexible development for future requirements. Is something like below possible? If not, what alternatives do I have to accommodate such a design?

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import RuntimeValueProvider


class IOPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input_bucket', type=str)
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--output_table', type=str)


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(IOPipelineOptions)
data = (p
        | 'ReadCollection' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(user_options.input_bucket)
        |   #Transform data(i.e custom parser) dynamic
            #Write Data To BigQuery Table i.e user_options.output_table
        )
```

I tried using the Google provided template but I wanted to stray away from using Javascript UDF's. Most of my dev team is comfortable using Python. I'd like to stay away from this solution if possible.